# Does mongodb have a document timeout option like Redis?

Tags: mongodb

Does mongodb have an analogous capability to Redis's key timeouts? I need this to "health check" different machines simultaneously feeding data to Mongo.

Each machine is responsible for collecting a different set of data, but if one of them goes down, then I need another one to know about that, and take over the dead machine's tasks (as well as keeping its own capture tasks running). The problem is, how do I know if one machine has gone down?

My idea was to have each "feed machine" constantly (say every second) update a health-document collection with its status as a document with, say, a 5 second timeout. If that document disappears, then that machine has gone down.

Can this be done with Mongo? Or is there another design pattern that does not involve constantly polling for each machine's data stream feeds into Mongo, that would achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MongoDB has TTL (Time To Live) collections.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)

For your problem of determining health of a machine I would say coupling that with MongoDB or any datastore would not be a great idea.

You can have a master/orchestrator which receives pings/heartbeats from different machines and then assign tasks accordingly.

Comment: Brilliant thank you. By ping, you mean a communications pattern that does not go through Mongodb, is what I am assuming you are saying? It is a heterogenous set of machines (data capture are windows, servers and data consumers are ubuntu). Using Python, what library can you suggest to do this pinging?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne you are right. I was talking about a communication mechanism. Something like Zookeeper should help here. Not sure whether there is a python equivalent.